# Room database not prepopulating on one phone, but it does on another

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have an application which uses android's room database, and it worked perfectly fine on my physical phone. However, at some point no data was prepopulating tha database on installation. I tried the same thing with both another physical phone and with the emulator and it works perfectly. Any clues on what is happening?

(Database is created, and I can insert, read and delete afterwards)

Comment: have you uninstalled the App on the phone where it's not working?

Comment: @MikeT yes, and it still doesn't

Answer (score 0):

It suddenly started working again, I don't really know what happened

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).